# How to form multiple clusters of given size from a set of points?

Tags: cluster-analysis

Let us consider a 2 dimensional space. There are 100 points in it. So, each point has its $x$ and $y$ coordinates. I want to form 10 clusters. Each cluster has 10 points.

How can I form such clusters.

Comment: See [`FindClusters`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html).

Comment: Your "definition" of a cluster needs some clarification. For a start: When are two points in the point cloud "adjacent"?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I have x and y-axis coordinates of 100 points. I want to perform clustring over these points. Lets say I want to generate 10 clusters, each cluster with exactly 10 elements.

Comment: The result is depend by distance of points to cluster center. Consider this situation: cluster 1-points[1-11]-center1, cluster2-ponits[12-20]-center2. there are 11 points in cluster1, 9 points in cluster2, we can move point 11 to cluster2? But distance[center1, point11]< distance[center2, point11], is this valid?

Answer (score 3):

You need an exact definition of "adjacent" as Henrik already said, because it is the bread and butter of finding clusters of *similar* elements.

Otherwise, you can start with

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
ListPlot[FindClusters[pts, 10], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.05]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. How do you gurantee that each cluster has 10 points?

Answer (score 2):

Here an example for constructing two clusters, which can easily expanded to n clusters:

```
cstart = {1, 2};
```

Now this forms the "start"-cluster

```
   clusterStart = (# + cstart) & /@ 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], {10^3, 2}];
```

Next a bunch of clusters, somewhat drifting apart from the start cluster

```
clusterList = 
  Table[(# + cstart + delta*{1, 1}) & /@ 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], {10^3, 2}], {delta, 0.5,
     4, 0.3}];
```

Lastly, forming the clusters:

```
clusterList = {clusterStart, #} & /@ clusterList;
```

Finally plotting the resulting point sets:

```
With[{out = 
   Graphics[{{Red, Point[#[[1]]]}, {Green, Point[#[[2]]]}}, 
      Frame -> True] & /@ clusterList},
 GraphicsGrid[Partition[out, 3], ImageSize -> Large]
 ]
```

this delivers:

[image]