# How to find clusters with same cluster sizes?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, cluster-analysis

I have a set of 71 data points. Each data point is represented by its latitude and longitude. I want to divide them into 12 clusters. The first 11 cluster will have exactly 6 points each and 12th cluster will have 5 elements.

Can this be done in Mathematica?

Comment: can you give an example of data and expected result?

Comment: Is this question significantly different from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184663/121 ?

Comment: Please post your data, so it is hard to understand: "The first 11 cluster will have exactly 11 points each" is 121 points? What about overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
Partition[Range@71, UpTo[11], 6]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
>     15, 16, 17}, {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}, {19, 20, 
>     21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}, {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 
>     32, 33, 34, 35}, {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41}, {37, 
>     38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47}, {43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 
>     49, 50, 51, 52, 53}, {49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 
>     59}, {55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65}, {61, 62, 63, 64, 
>     65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71}, {67, 68, 69, 70, 71}}